# Listing Transactions that Exceed Sum Threshold

Tags: sql-server-2008

I work for a credit card company.  Our database has a customer table and a transaction table. Fields in the customer table are SSN and CustomerKey.  Fields in the transaction table are CustomerKey, transaction date (Transdate), and transaction amount (TransAmt).

I need a report that can list each transaction for each ssn where the sum of the transaction amounts > 1000 within a two day period in 2012.

Here is an example of the raw data in the Transaction Table:

```
Trans#-----CustKey-----Date--------Amount
1-----------12345----01/01/12--------$600
2-----------12345----01/02/12--------$500
3-----------67890----01/03/12--------$700
4-----------12345----04/01/12--------$600
5-----------67890----04/02/12--------$600
```

Here is an example of the raw data in the Customer Table:

```
CustKey-----SSN
12345------123456789
67890------123456789
```

Here are the results I need:

```
Trans#------SSN---------Date---------Amount---Group Key
1--------123456789----01/01/12---------$600--------1
2--------123456789----01/02/12---------$500--------1 
2--------123456789----01/02/12---------$500--------2 
3--------123456789----01/03/12---------$700--------2
4--------123456789----04/01/12---------$600--------3
5--------123456789-----04/02/12--------$600--------3
```

As you can see in my results, Trans# 2 is listed twice as it was part of a group of transaction that exceeded $1000 in 2 days. Each group of transaction that exceeded 1000 is identified by a group key.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I think it is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have the lead/lag functionality, my approach is as follows.

First, determine the pairs of dates that meet your criteria.  You can do this with a self join to find transactions on pairs of dates that meet your criteria.  Now, you have a description of the dates, but these are on one row rather than on two rows.

So, you need to join this back to the transactions.  First on the first date, and then again on the second date.  This double join (actually left outer joins) will allow the transactions to appear more than once if more than one criteria is met.

Here is a query that attempts this:

```
with pairs as
     (select t.trans, t.ssn, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
      from (select t.*, c.ssn
            from transaction t join
                 customer c
                 on t.custkey = c.custkey
           ) t join
           (select t.*, c.ssn
            from transaction t join
                 customer c
                 on t.custkey = c.custkey
           ) tnext
           on t.ssn= tnext.ssn and
              t.date = tnext.date - 1
      group by t.trans, t.ssn, t.amount
      having sum(t.amount) > 1000
     ) pairs
select t.trans, c.ssn
from transactions t. join
     customer c
     on t.custkey = c.custkey left outer join
     pairs pfirst
     on t.date = pfirst.mindate and
        c.custkey = pfirst.custkey left outer join
     pairs plast
     on t.date = plast.maxdate and
        c.custkey = plast.custkey
```